# c : parse hex number inside long string

Tags: c, parsing, hex, libxml2

I am parsing an XML file using libxml2, and I need to pull out a hex number
from an xml attribute. Now, lib2xml doesn't give a null terminated string
for the attribute, just pointers to the beginning and end of the attribute.

So, given `.........FILL:BB0011AA;...............`  (where dots indicate arbitrary
characters), and `char* begin` pointing to the F in `FILL`, and `char* end` pointing
to the semi-colon, how can I efficiently pull out the hex number, WITHOUT making
a copy into a null terminated string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like so:

```
unsigned int value;
if(sscanf(begin, "FILL:%x;", &value) != 1)
   printf("Parse error\n");
```

I think the above is safe even if the data at `begin` isn't a string at all, i.e. if it doesn't contain a `NUL` terminator. Since the `%x` will abort if any non-hexadecimal character is found, there shouldn't be any risk of it running off into la-la land in memory. I can't come up with a case where it would run amok.

Comment: Cool. I thought that begin had to point to a null terminated string.

Comment: `value` should actually be of type `unsigned int`.

Comment: Thanks, unwind. And, `begin` probably does have a null terminator, at the very end. But, obviously, I don't want parsing to get there, for performance reasons.

Comment: wouldn't strtoul be more efficient?  it avoids having to parse the format specifier etc and otherwise (afaik) works the same.